# Why did the close vote queue suddenly decrease in size

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

I don't know when this happened, but one day I looked at the review page and noticed a drastically reduced number of close votes:

[image]

Only 14k?! It used to be ~150k.

Is this a massive increase in close vote reviewing, the result of some improvement to the system, or a bug with the formatter?

Comment: It was high but it never ever touched 150K

Comment: It may be a lie, but at least it's a small number. And in the end isn't that what matters

Comment: @tbodt; you must have missed the close review party. We all got drunk last night and apparently reviewed about 120k questions. I have no idea who's bra was on my head this morning, though.